# android HTML parsing

Tags: android, html-parsing

how to parse HTML tag in android, file is stored in my local drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). It supports selecting elements using [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). Start with [this cookbook introduction](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document).

Kickoff example:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("/foo.html"), "UTF-8");
Elements links = document.select("a");
for (Element link : links) {
    String url = link.absUrl("href");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: <pre>i've tried like this but still getting ERORR </pre><pre>org.jsoup.nodes.Document document;
  try {
   document = Jsoup.parse(new File(
     "E:/Spike/Sixthsense/javahtmlparsing/src/test.html"),
     "UTF-8");

   Elements links = document.select("a");
   for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element link : links) {
    String url = link.absUrl("href");
    Toast.makeText(this, "URL  " + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
  } catch (IOException e) {

   Toast.makeText(this, "Error  " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
     .show();

  }</pre>